# How do I use .filter to return multiple values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have a div, with some CSS and javascript:

```js
var someCSS = {
  color: 'red',
};
         

$(".test > .sub").filter(function(index) {
   return $(this).text() == 'hello';
 }).css(someCSS);
```

```css
.test {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='test'>
  <div class='sub'>hello</div>
  <div class='sub'>stackoverflow</div>
</div>
```

The above will color the 'hello' red, but I don't understand how to add more values, eg 'hello' and 'stackoverflow'. I obviously can't do `return $(this).text() == 'hello' || 'stackoverflow';`, but I just can't figure out what to do!

Any suggestions will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an array of values and then check against it, this way, you can add more values as you want and then you could just use [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

```
var arr = ['hello', 'stackoverflow'];
```

and then

```
return arr.indexOf($(this).text()) > -1;
```

Comment: My values actually are in an array - I was making it simpler, but this looks even better!! Thanks :)

Comment: @downloader glad to have helped :)

Comment: @downloader `indexOf` takes an argument, in this case text and returns the index of the element if present, if not -1, which is on what we are comparing.

Comment: Thanks - that makes much more sense :)

Comment: @downloader more glad to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".test > .sub").filter(function(index) {
   return $(this).text() == 'hello' || $(this).text() === 'stackoverflow';
 }).css(someCSS);
```

or

```
var values = [
  'hello',
  'stackoverflow'
]

$(".test > .sub").filter(function(index) {
   return values.indexOf($(this).text()) > -1 
 }).css(someCSS);
```

Answer (score 1):

Close, you need to compare again:

```
return $(this).text() == 'hello' || $(this).text() == 'stackoverflow'
```

Comment: ` 'hello' || "stackoverflow"` will always return 'hello' since the value `hello == true` (but not ===)

Comment: Although you were the first, @Amit helped me a bit more due to the array thing! I'd +1 you again if I could!!

Answer (score 1):

My own take on this problem is to use `Array.prototype.indexOf()`:

```
$(".test > .sub").filter(function(index) {
   return ['hello','stackoverflow'].indexOf($(this).text().trim()) > -1;
 }).addClass('someCSS');
```

The above approach allows for an array of strings that you wish to find to be used, rather than explicitly comparing and evaluating a number of strings within the anonymous function; albeit, in this example, I've constructed that array within the same function for brevity.

```js
$(".test > .sub").filter(function(index) {
  return ['hello','stackoverflow'].indexOf($(this).text().trim()) > -1;
}).addClass('someCSS');
```

```css
.someCSS {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='test'>
  <div class='sub'>hello</div>
  <div class='sub'>stackoverflow</div>
</div>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).
  - [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).